# VisualGDB Embedded Project Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, stm32

I am using VisualGDB to build an Emedded Project using Visual StudionCommunity 2013. I chose STM32F4xxxx as my device type. I am getting the below error while doing, clean, build or rebuild

```
Error   6   error MSB3073: The command ""\VisualGDB.exe" /rebuild "C:\MyWork\experiments\Embedded\EmbeddedProject1\EmbeddedProject2\EmbeddedProject2.vcxproj" "/solution:C:\MyWork\experiments\Embedded\EmbeddedProject1\EmbeddedProject1.sln" "/config:Debug" "/platform:ARM"" exited with code 9009.  

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   43  5   EmbeddedProject2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and my problem was that I had not the beginning of a path in my makefile (I had just `".../NameOfTheLib"` and I replace by `"C:/Documents/...AllMyPath/NameOfTheLib"`) and now it works and I can send my project by SSH.